# How to copy/paste rigid-body-constraints in 2.73 rc1?

Tags: objects, workflow, constraints

How do I copy/paste rigid-body constraints in 2.73 rc1? (I Have a lot of objects)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Copy from Active`. To do this, first select all your objects that will receive the *Rigid Body* physics, and then the one which already as it; This is so that the object which has the *Rigid Body* physics becomes the *Active* object.

Then, open the `Toolbar` (press <kbd>T</kbd>) and switch to the `Physics` tab; There, you can press `Copy from Active` to copy all the physics to the new objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but NOT working for me.

Comment: Why?  What happens; is there any error message?

Comment: Rigid body constrains will not activate at all, no errors as far as I can tell.

Comment: That seems like a bug, try using 2.73 (the stable version).

Comment: Allready at 2.73 stable.

Comment: If you're sure you've followed the steps properly, report it as a bug

Answer (score 0):

For me, this procedure copy rigid body properties from one object to the others, but:
Can't see in physics tab when the others objects are selected. 
Can't copy the Rigid Body Collisions > Shape settings.
(Blender 2.72b)